# how to parse the json branched value

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, android-emulator

I am new to android programming.And i was trying to make toast the value of user id in my android app by parsing it but error says no value for user. How to take input from json data in android? I have attached my logcat errors below.Can anyone Please help me? Thanks in advanced

```
"status": "SUCCESS",
"msg": "Login Successful",
"data": {
    "user": {
        "id": "6",
        "first_name": "e",
        "last_name": "ff",
        "address": "dr",
        "mobile": "55",
        "email": "rokes1990@live.com",
        "password": "4124bc0a9335c27f086f24ba207a4912",
        "pwd_reset_key": "",
        "name_on_card": "",
        "card_number": "",
        "expiry_date": "",
        "cvv": "",
        "tdatetime": "2014-07-11 02:55:08"
    }
}
```

LogCat error:

```
09-05 03:36:00.567: D/dalvikvm(2227): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 379K, 8% free 5765K/6220K, paused 76ms, total 82ms
09-05 03:36:02.077: W/Response(2227): {"GET":[],"POST":{"action":"login","app_secret":"jkhljkUILJGJkljhkjUGLG87796587687HGKJhghkjKUYGKJHjhgjUYGKUY7865876hgKUYGK","email":"rokes1990@live.com","password":"aa"},"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"Login Successful","data":{"user":{"id":"6","first_name":"e","last_name":"ff","address":"dr","mobile":"55","email":"rokes1990@live.com","password":"4124bc0a9335c27f086f24ba207a4912","pwd_reset_key":"","name_on_card":"","card_number":"","expiry_date":"","cvv":"","tdatetime":"2014-07-11 02:55:08"}}}
09-05 03:36:02.107: W/System.err(2227): org.json.JSONException: No value for user
09-05 03:36:02.117: W/System.err(2227):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
09-05 03:36:02.117: W/System.err(2227):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:515)
09-05 03:36:02.147: W/System.err(2227):     at example.atlcitylimo.Main.postLoginData(Main.java:116)
09-05 03:36:02.147: W/System.err(2227):     at example.atlcitylimo.Main.onClick(Main.java:181)
09-05 03:36:02.147: W/System.err(2227):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
09-05 03:36:02.147: W/System.err(2227):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
09-05 03:36:02.147: W/System.err(2227):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-05 03:36:02.147: W/System.err(2227):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-05 03:36:02.147: W/System.err(2227):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-05 03:36:02.157: W/System.err(2227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-05 03:36:02.157: W/System.err(2227):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 03:36:02.157: W/System.err(2227):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-05 03:36:02.157: W/System.err(2227):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-05 03:36:02.157: W/System.err(2227):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-05 03:36:02.157: W/System.err(2227):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected String getId(String result) { 
    try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("data"));
    JSONObject user = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("user"));
    String id = user.getString("id");
    return id;
    }catch (Exception e) {
     Log.d("error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
   }
   return null;

}
```

Comment: @mystic_knight,your are welcome,but don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use Volley for parsing json strings. check the "Making JSON request" in the following link:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Volley provides an easy to make json requests. If you are expecting json object in the response, you should use `JsonObjectRequest` class or if the response is json array, `JsonArrayRequest` class should be used. `StringRequest` class will be used to fetch any kind of string data. The response can be json, xml, html or plain text.

You can start with JsonObjectRequest to get the JSONObject:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //response is the JSONObject that you get from the request
                        //you can play with that request to get the exact info you want
                        String status = response.getString("status");
                        String msg = response.getString("msg");
                        JSONObject data = null;
                        try{
                            data = response.getJSONObject("data"); 
                        }catch (JSONException e1) {
                             e1.printStackTrace();
                        } 

                        JSONObject user = null;
                        try{
                            user = data.getJSONObject("user"); 
                        }catch (JSONException e1) {
                             e1.printStackTrace();
                        } 

                        String id = user.getString("id");
                        String first_name = user.getString("first_name");
                        //and goes on for the rest of the user info
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

And also you need to add this request to a request queue

```
// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag_json_arry);
```

And your AppController class is as follows:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally add to your Manifest.xml the following ander the `<application>` tag

```
<application
        android:name="info.androidhive.volleyexamples.app.AppController"
```